# Why is the plotted line blurry?

Tags: python, matplotlib, antialiasing

I have code that creates the following plot:

[image]

Zooming in on the line, we can see that instead of being just black, it has a black core and is gray/slightly transparent on the sides (see figure below). Is it possible to make the line fully black?

[image]

Here is the code that is used for the plotting:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np


plt.plot([10,10],[10,20],color='k',linewidth=1)
plt.show()
```

Increasing the dpi does not work, and I want the linewidth to remain the same.

Comment: Antialiasing is essential for getting smooth looking angled lines and curves.  Unfortunately it has the side effect of blurring perfectly horizontal and vertical lines.  You can't get one without the other.

Answer (score 2):

The effect you see is called [antialiasing](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/winforms/advanced/antialiasing-with-lines-and-curves?view=netframeworkdesktop-4.8) and important in computer graphics to make lines drawn at any angle look similar when drawn with the same thickness.

Almost always, the measure for distances isn't an integer value when calculated in pixels. Without antialiasing x and y positions need to be rounded to the nearest pixel.

[`plt.plot()`](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.plot.html) (and similar functions) has an optional argument `antialiased=` which you can set to `False` to see how things look like. Depending on your specific application, this might work for you.

Here is an example. It uses `lw=0.2` to show the effect more strongly. With thicker lines, the same effect will still be there, but less visible.  Note that matplotlib measures lines in "points" (1/72 of an inch, similar to the "points" used to indicate font size). Due to different rounding and positions not falling onto integer pixels, some lines are thicker, and diagonal lines look very jagged.

```py
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

plt.plot([i // 10 * 10 for i in range(0, 100, 5)], [0, 10] * 10, antialiased=False, color='black', lw=0.2)
```

[image: turning off antialiasing]

Zoomed in view:

[image: zoomed in on image without antialiasing]

PS: Here is an example with `plt.contour()`:

```py
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

xs, ys = np.meshgrid(np.linspace(0, 1, 30), np.linspace(0, 1, 20))
zs = np.random.randn(*xs.shape).cumsum(axis=0).cumsum(axis=1)

plt.contour(xs, ys, zs, cmap='Spectral', antialiased=False)
plt.show()
```

This is how it looks like overall and zoomed-in:

[image: non-antialiased contour plot]

I tested this with maptlotlib 3.5.3 on Windows, with the 'TkAgg' backed.

An alternative would be to save your plot to a vector format (e.g. `.svg`) and do the further processing via an editor such as InkScape.

Comment: Thanks, this actually worked for my example plot. However, what I really wanted to do involves using plt.contour() and for some reason the antialiased=False makes no difference at all when using countour plots. Any ideas why?